# What is the difference between random() and {random()}?

Tags: kotlin

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9011/lessons/14fb1ae9-8a2e-48ee-9620-68c87c5f833b/concepts/7ce11834-0ff4-4dc9-8b89-81309af23424
From above tutorial
Quiz Question

What is the difference between

val random1 = random()
val random2 = {random()}

Try it out in REPL or a file:
The tutorial answer is:
random1 has a value assigned at compile time, and the value never changes when the variable is accessed.

random2 has a lambda assigned at compile time, and the lambda is executed every time the variable is referenced, returning a different value.

I did try it out in PERL but I got

```
error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun <T> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.random(): TypeVariable(T) defined in kotlin.collections
```

so I wrote codes to test tutorial answer but I got opposite result from tutorial answer.

random1 is executed every time the variable is referenced, returning a different value.
random2 always print out as "Function0<java.lang.Integer>".  I guess tutorial answer is correct. How come my codes shows differently than tutorial answer? What is the difference between random() and {random()}? Please elaborate a little bit when you response since I am new to kotlin and you can tell from my question.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    gamePlay(rollDice())
}

val rollDice = {Random().nextInt(3)+1}
val random1 = Random().nextInt(3)
val random2 = {Random().nextInt(3)}

fun gamePlay(XXXdiceRoll:Int){
    // do something with the dice roll
    println(XXXdiceRoll)
    println(XXXdiceRoll)
    println(random1)
    println(random1)
    println(random2)
    println(random2)
}
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a basic Kotlin tutorial before this. However what you specifically need to answer the question is some knowledge of what a *lambda* is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally quoted Udacity, their explanations are wrong. `random1`’s value is not assigned at compile time because `random()` is called at runtime when the class is first used. Only then is its value assigned. Afterwards, in the same application session, the value will remain constant. But the same compiled app will have different values for it on separate sessions of the application.

And `random2`’s lambda is not executed every time the variable is referenced. It is executed only when it is invoked with a call to `invoke()` (or operator equivalent). The lambda object itself will always be the same instance.

So, your own test confirms how they described both cases incorrectly.

Comment: I read 5 times your answer and do some research but still don't fully understand what you wrote but thank you for helping.

Comment: If you have follow-up questions I can try to explain better.

Comment: (1)what is the printout of random2, "Function0<java.lang.Integer>", means? Please explain it in a less technical way with plain English.

Comment: (2) Why println(random2) prints out "Function0<java.lang.Integer>" instead of random number? I want println(random2) actually print out random numbers like println(XXXdiceRoll) instead of printing out "Function0<java.lang.Integer>" Can you show me how to do it? Thank you!!!

Comment: `random2` is referencing (which means it is a variable holding a reference to) a functional object. It behaves very similarly to any other variable with a reference to a class instance, but the difference is that you can call it like a function. When you use `println` on it, it is returning the type of the function. In this case it is a function with 0 parameters and returns an Integer. If you want the result of the functional object, you have to call it like a function, so you would use `random2()`. So if you want to print the result of using the function you would put `println(random2())`.

Comment: I saw your reply right away and spent 2 hrs to try and research what you wrote. (1) What is the functional object in my case? (2) println(random2()) works and I try to add println(random2) into a new function to print out another random number while gamePlay(rollDice()) works at the same time. 2nd method works too. Thank you for your inspiration. (3) Can you try to help me with my very first question, "Kotlin: Is it impossible to combine repeat() and while() to loop 3 times?

Comment: The functional object is the function defined by the lambda `{ Random().nextInt(3) }`.

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.